# how does duct limit sensor work?

Tags: hvac

I have a dual-fuel (propane) split system heat pump.   The A/C is not working.  I have traced it down to the "fossil fuel" board.   It fails to assert (put 24vac) on the yellow wire that goes to the compressor and tells it to turn on.  It correctly asserts the orange wire, that tells the compressor reversing valve to be in cooling mode.

Perhaps the fossil-fuel board has gone bad. But maybe there's another explanation.  It has two 2-pin connectors, to which are connected 4 wires that go to the vicinity of the indoor coil.   On the board, the connectors say "LIMIT" and on the wiring diagram it says something about "duct".  I guess they sense air flow, or temperature in the air stream.

Question: if I want to defeat/disable these inputs to the fossil-fuel board to see if they are the culprit, how should I do it (if it's possible to say here) ?   Disconnect the wires ?   Short the terminals (on each connector) together ?  As best I can tell, the board has no fuse.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I connected the thermostat yellow "cool" wire to the compressor's yellow "turn on" wire (the one the fossil-fuel board fails to assert, thereby bypassing it), and now the A/C works fine.

People may recall that I just replaced the compressor's contactor (which had failed after one year).  I checked the capacitor and it looks good.   I cannot fathom how the failed contactor might've caused the fossil-fuel board to fail.  There's not even a direct connection - the compressor's control board is in the signal path, and it's still fine (since the A/C works properly, with the bypass I described, including the delay to prevent short-cycling).   The system is 25 years-old, so I suppose two independent but virtually-simultaneous failures is not crazy.

It's been suggested that I get a dual-fuel capable thermostat (like the Nest 'E' model) and use that with an outdoor temperature sensor to eliminate the fossil-fuel board.   But I'd still like to know what's going on.

Comment: Think a duct limit might be a safety sensor for duct blockage.  The fuel either can't get enough air(intake) or the more dangerous exhaust is blocked and CO gas could build up and kill you.

Comment: Most sensors in ductwork are simple open or closed switches, with inducer fans they can be a  pressure switch or a vane switch and sometimes both.  Without even the number of wires for the inputs we could guess (open the connection and see if something changes) the other state of connecting the 2 points?  Would be common for a safety but suggesting that with limited info would be foolish.

Comment: There are two ports on the fossil-fuel board, and each has two wires.   They travel to the indoor cool as a bundle of 4 wires.   Makes sense that you can't really say from afar, but thanks.

Comment: My HVAC guy - moonlghting cryogenic tech, who I feel bad about bothering about a system that he installed 25 years ago - says let's install a dual-fuel capable thermostat and ditch the fossil-fuel board.   Approves of my hack to get the A/C working.   So don't need to do anything till winter.